# Can you explain the output of this java program using enum?

Tags: java, enums

```
class Ideone
{
    enum Members{
        A(1),B(2),C(3);  // I have 3 enum constants here
        private int size;
        Members(int size){
            //System.out.println("Initializing var with size = "+size);
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.print("main ");
        // your code goes here
        for (Members i: Members.values()){
            System.out.print(i.name());
            System.out.println(i.size);
        }       
    }
}
```

Here goes the Output of the program-

main
A
0
B
0
C
0

Why is the size value not printed as 1, 2 and 3 instead of 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you did not map the size attribute. Change the enum constructor to:

```
Members(int size){
    this.size = size;
}
```

Btw: you should always mark enum fields as `final` as enums just exist once (singletons). So change `private int size` to `private final int size`

Comment: Also, it's better to create getter for `size` field: `public int getSize() { return size; }`